# GIT push fails from Windows Machine to SFTP site mapped by win-sshfs

Tags: windows, git, sftp, msysgit, sshfs

We decided to use our SFTP site as a bare GIT repository for our windows development machines.  We were able to create a repository, clone it to the dev machines, and push our initial checkin.  Subsequent pushes at a later date have failed:

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding 
an object to repository database./objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: failed to push some refs to 'w:/mvc-solution.git'
```

Our setup:

I am on a windows machine and have a drive letter W mapped to our sftp site.  I am able to map my drive W: to the sftp site using [win-sshfs](https://web.archive.org/web/20170304124936/http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/).

We installed git on our windows machine using [msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/).  `git version` says this:

```
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0
```

We did a `cd /w` to get to our repository location, and then ran `git init --bare mvc-solution.`. Then we cloned the repository to the developer machine ( `git clone mvc-solution.git c:/myDeveloperCodeRepo` ) and then changed into the developer directory ( `cd c:/myDeveloperCodeRepo` ).  We dropped the source code into the directory, ran `git add ...` and `git commit -m 'Initial Checkin'`.  We then ran `git push origin master` **without any problem**.  We verified our code is on the SFTP site via FileZilla and also via the mapped W: drive letter.  Elated, we told our boss that we created a repository with our SFTP site to manage our Windows code.

Then, one day later, we made changes to the developer machine code (added a directory with some files -- spreadsheets, text files, images).  We added the files, commited them, and then tried to run `git push origin master`.  No joy. Instead, we got the message above (`...failed to push...`). In other words, were not able to push the files to the sftp bare repository anymore.

We remounted the mapped drive connection (win-sshfs) without any problem, and made sure we could access the sftp site using just Windows Explorer and the W: drive.  We also tried running `git config core.sharedRepository true` ; we have tried different internet connections, both over wifi and ethernet from different locations.  No luck.  Again, we are not on Linux, Mac or any other Unix-type machine.  Other than GIT, we aren't using any unix-like shell and we are just using typical Windows tools to manage our files.  The **same** developer machine that did the initial checkin is the developer machine that attempted to do the subsequent push.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I found out how to fix things.  The problem seemed to be with the sshfs program I was using, and not GIT.  To get this to work, I downloaded [Eldos Net Drive Free](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/download-release.php#product)

Then, I set the timeout settings to 60 seconds (just to make sure, might not be necessary), after clicking on the profile settings button. I was able to almost push with GIT, but I got an error message saying "couldn't set refs/heads/master".  I checked the repository and there was not any problem with the HEAD file.  In the end, it appears GIT tries to do some file move/rename action, which wasn't supported over the mapped SFTP drive.  But, in my case, the fix was easy.  I went into the profile settings again (for the Eldos SFTP net drive program), and put a checkmark in the checkbox that says "Delete existing target before moving."  I ran the "git push origin master" command, and it went through.  It was really slick.  So, now we have a shared GIT repository using the SFTP site, which we map using that net drive program, and then use the Windows Git program to run GIT commands.

Update:
OK, it appears that Eldos Net Drive no longer works and is no longer supported.  This solution will no longer be available as a fix for using Eldos Net Drive to map drives to an SFTP server.  Also, several errors that occurred with other SFTP drive mapping tools now occur with Eldos Net Drive.  None of the settings available in the new version of Eldos Net Drive fixed the problem.

Comment: I regret to say that your update is misleading at least. SFTP Net Drive is actively developed and maintained. However, there's no support provided for Free version (and never was any support offered). As for your issues, they seem to be caused by the server, not the client (as multiple clients don't work with the same server).